# Import error when trying to import python module from other folder

Tags: python, import, python-import

This is my project structure:

```
/my_project
    /first_folder
        first.py
    /second_folder
        second.py
```

second.py

```
def hello():
    print('hello')
```

first.py

```
from ..second_folder import second

second.hello()
```

when i run first.py i get the following error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Please do not edit questions to include an answer. Keep in mind that this is a Q&A site; we want clear questions that stand *as questions* to suit the format. This is **not a discussion forum** so we don't "update" the OP to show progress or indicate that a problem was solved; we only edit it for clarity and tone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally when you run your script as the main module, you shouldn't use relative imports in it. That's because how Python resolves relative imports (using `__package__` variable and so on...)

This is also documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references):

> Note that relative imports are based on the name of the current
> module. Since the name of the main module is always `"__main__"`,
> modules intended for use as the main module of a Python application
> must always use absolute imports.

There are ways to make this work for example by hacking `__package__`, using `-m` flag, add some path to `sys.path`(where Python looks for modules) **but** the simplest and general solution is to always use absolute imports in your main script.

When you run a script, Python automatically adds the directory of your script to the `sys.path`, which means anything inside that directory (here `first_folder` is recognizable by interpreter. But your `second_folder` is not in that directory, you need to add the path to the `my_project`(which has the `second_folder` directory) for that.

Change your `first.py` to:

```py
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, "PATH TO /my_project")

from second_folder import second

second.hello()
```

This way you can easily go into `first_folder` directory and run your script like: `python first.py`.

Final words: With absolute imports, you don't have much complexity. Only think about "*where you are*" and "*which paths are exists in the `sys.path`*".

Answer (score -1):

There are several sources for this error but, probably, if your project directory is `my_project` then you don't need `..` in the import statement.

```
from second_folder import second
```

Comment: You mean: ```from second_folder import second``` ?

Comment: `my_project` directory is the root folder but it's not in the path. That's because `first.py` is not directly inside `my_project` folder. The only path that gets inserted into `sys.path` is `first_directory` - the directory of the script.